# Mysql dropping inserts with triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

Using mysql 5.6. I have two tables. One has a whitelist of hashes. When I insert a new row into the other table, I want to first compare the hash in the insert statement to the whitelist. If it's in the whitelist, I don't want to do the insert (less data to plow through later). The inserts are generated from another program and are text files with sql statements.

I've been playing with triggers, and almost have it working:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Filelist` BEFORE INSERT ON `filelist`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF(
SELECT count( md5hash ) FROM whitelist WHERE md5hash = new.hash ) >0
THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Can not have duplicates';

END IF ;

END
```

But there's a problem. The Signal throwing up the error stops the import. I want to skip that line, not stop the whole import.

Some searching didn't find any way to silently skip the import.

My next idea was to create a duplicate table definition, and redirect the insert to that dup table. But the old and new don't seem to apply to table names.

Other then adding an ignore column to my table then doing a mass drop based on that column after the import, is there any way to achieve my goal? I'm having problems with this too [Ignore is a tinyint(1)]:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER whitelisted
BEFORE INSERT ON filelist
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (select count(md5hash) from whitelist where md5hash=new.hash) > 0 THEN
  SET Ignore = true;
  END IF;
END$$
/* This is now "END$$" not "END;" */

/* Reset the delimiter back to ";" */
DELIMITER ;

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') THEN SET Ignore = true;
END IF; END' at line 4
```

Any suggestions? I've also tried

```
SET Ignore = 1;
SET Ignore = '1';
SET new.Ignore = {all of the above};
```

Comment: If this is possible, I don't know how. For anyone reading this post, I worked around the problem by running a delete after the inserts are done to remove any row with a matching hash in the whitelist. The query I used is: delete from filelist where (select count(md5hash) from whitelist where md5hash=hash) > 0  I will keep watching this in case I do get a working answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I follow this specification:

> I have two tables. One has a whitelist of hashes. When I insert a new row into the other table, I want to first compare the hash in the insert statement to the whitelist. If it's in the whitelist, I don't want to do the insert

My first attempt would be like this:

```
INSERT INTO filelist (filename, hash)
SELECT "myfile", "ABCD" FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT md5hash FROM whitelist where md5hash = "ABCD"    
);
```

I don't think you need triggers for this at all unless there are missing details in your requirements.

Comment: Mysql inserts don't support where clauses, so this won't work. It's a good idea. I thought of it too (great minds think alike) before I looked at triggers because of the lack of support for where clauses.

Comment: Did you actually tried this query? I tested it using MySQL 5.6

Comment: Yes. It gave me a syntax error. My statement was:INSERT INTO fileaudit.filelist (rsTime, CName, OS, Path, FileName, Hash) Values ('20131010121919', 'HOU1287', 'WIN_7', 'C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\', 'cscript.exe', '3d58143149fbe29c3a43baf14277c6b2') WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT md5hash FROM whitelist where md5hash = '3d58143149fbe29c3a43baf14277c6b2');  and the hash is in the whitelist. Error was #1064 <snip> near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT md5hash FROM whitelist where md5hash = '3d58143149fbe29c' at line 1

Comment: That's not analog to my example. That's an `INSERT ... VALUES` and my code is an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement. Change the `VALUES` list for a select statement (the `DUAL` table is magic.)

Comment: I think the correct code would be `INSERT INTO filelist (rsTime, CName, OS, Path, FileName, Hash) SELECT '20131010121919', 'HOU1287', 'WIN_7', 'C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\', 'cscript.exe', '3d58143149fbe29c3a43baf14277c6b2' FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT md5hash FROM whitelist where md5hash = '3d58143149fbe29c3a43baf14277c6b2');`

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're doing some kind of ON INSERT-trigger.
You need to add the following statement to your trigger to make it work as wanted:

```
FOR EACH ROW
```

This will make the trigger execute once on every row.

Comment: That is not the problem here. OP shows only the relevant part of the trigger.

Comment: As I read it, the problem is that if one row is already in the whitelist table, it skips the whole rowset - which is what OP wants to avoid. If I misunderstood it, maybe the question needs to be updated with some clarifications.

Comment: Simon's interpretation of the issue (comment above) is correct. Sadly, the answer is not. I created this trigger via phpmyadmin. It did add the "for each row" automatically.